# How to connect the dots ? (the dots are randomly positioned HTML elements)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code to generate random points with a maximum distance from another element I have in the page:

```
function drawPoints (maxdistance, npoints) {
  var start = $('#startingPoint').position();
  var draw = document.getElementById('draw');

  var i = npoints;
  while(i--) {
    var n = document.createElement('div');
    n.style.position = 'absolute';
    n.style.top = ( - (Math.random() * maxdistance) -10 + start.top).toString() + 'px';
    n.style.left = ( - (Math.random() * maxdistance) + 50 + start.left).toString() + 'px';
    n.style.width = '6px';
    n.style.height = '6px';
    n.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    n.style.borderRadius = '6px';
    draw.appendChild(n);
  }
}
```

For an example, `drawPoints(150, 20);` would draw 20 points with a maximum distance of 150 from the starting point.

The question is, how do I draw some kind of arcs or lines to connect some of this dots ?

Comment: probably it would be better generate these points on a `canvas` element so to be easier create some joining arcs

Comment: Can you help with that ? Maybe point me to some good tutorial for this ? I'm really not comfortable with canvas...

Comment: Not an answer, so commenting: You might look at using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: after a quick search on google: see http://html5tutorial.com/how-to-draw-a-point-with-the-canvas-api/ and http://www.snippetdirectory.com/html5/drawing-arc-between-two-points-using-canvas/

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo: In particular. [this demo](http://raphaeljs.com/curver.html) seems relevant. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the canvas and other new features is very good, but I think that *almost* ALL things can be re-programmed with very simple built-in functions (and of course without jQuery).

This is a cross-browser function to connect the dots:

```
function connectDots(xA,yA,xB,yB)
{
    var a=document.createElement("div");
    var r=180*Math.atan2(yB-yA,xB-xA)/Math.PI;
    a.setAttribute("style","width:"+Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xA-xB,2)+Math.pow(yA-yB,2))+"px;height:1px;position:absolute;background-color:black;top:"+yA+"px;left:"+xA+"px;-moz-transform:rotate("+r+"deg);-moz-transform-origin:0px 0px;-webkit-transform:rotate("+r+"deg);-webkit-transform-origin:0px 0px;transform:rotate("+r+"deg);transform-origin:0px 0px;-ms-transform:rotate("+r+"deg);-ms-transform-origin:0px 0px;");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Four lines.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/3aG5H/2/

Comment: Thanks! But It's not making oblique lines... I played around with the coordinates but the slope is always 0...

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo I found that there was a lot of case where it's not working. Do you still need me to correct it?

Comment: Well I ended up writing the thing using canvas but it would be great for learning purposes because I didn't think this was possible...

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo I finally finished, now it handles ALL the cases.

Comment: I still can't work with it. This is what I tried to do: http://jsfiddle.net/4XgZL/ but it only created lines with zero slope...

Comment: What kind of browser are you using ? I'm using Chrome 20.0.1132.47, this is a screenshot of what I see: http://imgur.com/4MRuf

Comment: I am on firefox 13. I tested on Chrome, and it didn't work too. It's very strange because there is no functions that I use that may not be cross-browser. I will search the compatibility of each function I use.

Comment: Ohh great now I saw it, it was because of the -moz prefixes. I made 3 other functions (connectDotsFirefox, connectDotsChrome, connectDotsStandart) with all the different prefixations and the standart one, the standart doesn't still work but it should some time soon. Thanks for the answer, it's good to know this different method :) Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/9VZcg/

Comment: You saved me from a headache! I edited for a cross-browser solution with standart, `ms`, `moz`, and `webkit`. (And without re-calculating the rotation).

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo Look what I did with this function : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/73LJx/24/ (I don't really know how I did)